# Embed worksheet into another worksheet in same workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook which is meant to generate various forms (hence formatting is very important) for the grading of a course. There are a few grading worksheets which correspond to sections of the course, and a large worksheet which contains the marking rubrics for each section.

I've been asked to show (outside the printable region) the marking rubrics for each section in their respective grading worksheets. This should be beside (or perhaps below) the current content of the worksheets (which are basically a lot of boxes to fill marks in and cells containing text which label those boxes).

A simple copy paste (or reference) is out of the question because the formatting (column width, row height) difference between the grading worksheets and the rubric worksheet is significant.

How can I embed the relevant sections of the marking rubric worksheet to each grading worksheet? Ideally in such a way that changes to the marking rubric worksheet propagate to the display in the grading worksheets. I've already thought of taking a simple printscreen of the marking rubric worksheet and pasting it beside the grading worksheets, but that's a lot of work to regenerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dynamic image.

- Select the cells that you want to embed,
- click the Copy drop-down on the Home ribbon and select "Copy as Picture".
- Accept the defaults.
- paste the image to the desired position in the other worksheet.

So far you have a one-time snapshot of the cells. To make the image dynamic and reflect changes to the original cells,

- select the pasted image
- click inside the formula bar and enter a = sign
- click to the sheet with the original and select the same cells as above
- hit Enter.

Now you can change the data in the original and the dynamic screenshot will show the changes.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even know such a feature existed!

Comment: Just a note, in Excel 2010/2013 (I have both) you can just do a normal copy and then select 'Paste as linked image'

Comment: That's right. The option is fairly well hidden, hard to find and a bit cumbersome to apply, I find, though. Whereas you can link any kind of pasted image to any existing cell range using the formula bar method. Now you know. :-))